# How move elements one by one

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I use flex cards from internet in my website. How can I move elements one by one? I want to use one by one when my media max screen will be max 800px;
I tried `<br>` but isn't work :

https://codepen.io /veronicadev/pen/WJyOwG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give every of them a class or a div and then you can change their positions via css.